# Need help passing $(this) for an .on("click") callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its my first time using a function callback instead  of using an anonymous function for an on.("click") event. The console.log show the object key as undefined, and if I pass the $(this) ass the callback param it won't work

Can anyone please help pass help me figure this out. Any help would be really appreciated

```
   function getFreelancersInfo(elem){

        var id = elem.attr("id");
        /*@div_wrapper stores arbitrary data about the freelancer and also acts as a wrapper for
         *each freelancer  */
        var div_wrapper = $("div#"+id);

        var freelancer_info_obj = {

            first_name  : div_wrapper.attr("data-first-name"),
            last_name   : div_wrapper.attr("data-last-name"),
            email       : div_wrapper.attr("data-email")

        };

        //TODO create and send welcome email

        console.log(freelancer_info_obj);

        return false;
    }



    $(".approve").on("click",getFreelancersInfo()  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as the click callback inside which `this` will refer to the element targeted by the event

```
function getFreelancersInfo() {
    //here this refers to the clicked element
    var elem = $(this);
    var id = elem.attr("id");
    /*@div_wrapper stores arbitrary data about the freelancer and also acts as a wrapper for
     *each freelancer  */
    var div_wrapper = $("div#" + id);

    var freelancer_info_obj = {

        first_name: div_wrapper.attr("data-first-name"),
        last_name: div_wrapper.attr("data-last-name"),
        email: div_wrapper.attr("data-email")

    };

    //TODO create and send welcome email

    console.log(freelancer_info_obj);

    return false;
}



$(".approve").on("click", getFreelancersInfo);
```

---

If you don't want to change the method `getFreelancersInfo` then you can use an anonymous function has the handler which can call `getFreelancersInfo`

```
function getFreelancersInfo(elem) {

    var id = elem.attr("id");
    /*@div_wrapper stores arbitrary data about the freelancer and also acts as a wrapper for
      *each freelancer  */
     var div_wrapper = $("div#" + id);

     var freelancer_info_obj = {

         first_name: div_wrapper.attr("data-first-name"),
         last_name: div_wrapper.attr("data-last-name"),
         email: div_wrapper.attr("data-email")

     };

     //TODO create and send welcome email

     console.log(freelancer_info_obj);

     return false;
 }



$(".approve").on("click", function () {
    return getFreelancersInfo($(this))
});
```